# Solving mutually recursive constraints in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, constraint-programming

I am attempting to solve some mutually recursive constraints with SWI-Prolog. These constraints are relatively simple, but querying any of these predicates leads to infinite recursion:

```
%If X is an animal, then X is a bird or a mammal, and vice-versa.
animal(X) :- 
    (mammal(X);bird(X)),
    (male(X);female(X)).

male(X) :- animal(X).
female(X) :- animal(X).

bird(X) :- (X='parrot';X='pigeon'),animal(X).

mammal(X) :- (X='cat';X='dog'),animal(X).
```

Would it be possible to solve these constraints in Prolog without making them non-recursive?

I wrote a similar program with several base cases, but the query `mammal(X),bird(X)` still leads to infinite recursion instead of returning `false`:

```
%If X is an animal, then X is a bird or a mammal, and vice-versa.
animal(X) :- 
    (mammal(X);bird(X)).

bird('parrot').
bird('pigeon').
bird(X) :- (X='parrot';X='pigeon'),animal(X).

mammal('cat').
mammal('dog').
mammal(X) :- (X='cat';X='dog'),animal(X).
```

Comment: You realize that prolog predicates don't return values like functions do, right? So `dif(mammal(X), bird(X))` doesn't do what you probably think it does. In fact, it will *always* succeed since the terms `mammal(X)` and `bird(X)` are always necessarily different for any `X`. As Scott points out in his "answer", you don't have any facts or base cases.

Comment: @lurker Yes, the the `dif/2` predicates were redundant in this case. I edited the program to correct this problem.

Comment: They weren't just redundant. They were erroneously used. :p  Your existing logic, besides missing base case(s) as Scott points out, is circular. `animal/1` is defined in terms lf `male/1`, `female/1` and `mammal/1`. And `male/1`, `female/1`, and `mammal/1` are defined in terms of `animal/1`.

Comment: @lurker I updated the question again, and I encountered the same problem even after I added several base cases.

Comment: The new logic is *still* circular. `mammal` defined in terms of `animal`, and `animal` defined in terms of `mammal`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to find solutions for mutually recursive constraints using [constraint handling rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_Handling_Rules).

This is a set of mutually recursive constraints:

```
%If X is an animal, then X is a bird or a mammal, and vice-versa.
:- use_module(library(chr)).

:- chr_constraint mammal/2,bird/2,animal/1,male/1,female/1,species/2.

animal(X) <=> 
    (mammal(X,Species);bird(X,Species)),
    (male(X);female(X)).

male(X),female(X) ==> false.

bird(X,Species) <=> member(Species,[parrot,pigeon,crow]),species(X,Species).
bird(X,Species) ==> animal(X).

mammal(X,Species) <=> member(Species,[cat,dog,bull]),species(X,Species).
mammal(X,Species) ==> animal(X).

species(X,bull) ==> male(X).
```

...and this is the output of a query for this program:

```
?- male(X),mammal(X,Species).
male(_G67406)
species(_G67406,cat)
Species = cat
```

Answer (score 3):

Solving a recursive constraint requires one or more base cases; you have not provided any.  The problem isn't with Prolog; its with the problem definition.

Comment: Of course, it would be possible to re-write these mutually recursive constraints as non-recursive constraints, but my goal is to solve mutually recursive constraints without manually re-writing them. There is an [SMT solver](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/pubs/2012/3136/content.pdf) for Prolog that might make this easier.

Comment: There is *no* solver of any kind that can "solve" a recursive problem that does not have any base cases.  Adding base cases does not make it non-recursive; base cases are *part* of a recursive definition.

Comment: Q: "Would it be possible to solve these constraints in Prolog without making them non-recursive?"; I explained why the problem is ill-formed & thus cannot be solved.

Comment: @ScottHunter I updated the question again, but adding base cases did not completely solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're trying to get at is that you have birds and you have mammals. And you are further trying to establish that a creature is an animal if it is either a bird or a mammal.

The code currently over-specifies, and has circular logic.

Walking through the code...

```
animal(X) :- 
    (mammal(X); bird(X)).
```

This says that *`X` is an `animal` **if** `X` is a `mammal` or `X` is a `bird`*. So far, so good.

The description of `bird` reads:

```
bird('parrot').
bird('pigeon').
```

These are facts that indicate that a `parrot` is a `bird` and a `pigeon` is a `bird`. But then there's this rule:

```
bird(X) :- (X='parrot';X='pigeon'),animal(X).
```

Which says that *`X` is a `bird` **if** `X` is either a `parrot` or `pigeon`, AND if `X` is an `animal`*. The prior two facts already establish that `parrot` and `pigeon` are birds. Why is this rule necessary? And it further adds the condition that `X` is an `animal`, which is, in turn, defined in terms of `bird` and `mammal`, so is circular.

Similar holds true for the `mammal` definition. It has the needed facts for mammals:

```
mammal('cat').
mammal('dog').
```

And then *overspecifies* with circular logic:

```
mammal(X) :- (X='cat';X='dog'), animal(X).
```

The essence of what you need is simply:

```
bird('parrot').
bird('pigeon').

mammal('cat').
mammal('dog').

animal(X) :- 
    mammal(X); bird(X).
```

This logic defines what creatures are birds or mammals using facts, then provides a rule that says if a creature is known to be a bird or a mammal, then it's an animal.

Comment: This solution works in this case, but my goal is to solve mutually recursive constraints without manually rewriting them in a non-recursive form. In order to do this, I might need to use a [forward-chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_chaining) inference engine like [CHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_Handling_Rules).

Answer (score 2):

One solution to such problems is to simply enable your Prolog system's **tabling** mechanism.

For example, in SWI-Prolog (latest development version), if I simply add the following directives at the start of your program:

```
:- use_module(library(tabling)).

:- table animal/1.
```

Then I get for example:

```
?- animal(X).
false.

?- male(X).
false.

?- bird(X).
false.
```

So, in these cases, we still do not find any solution, but at least we get answers.